# Conditionally inline style a react component based on prop

Tags: css, reactjs, conditional-statements

I need to set the background color of a div based on a prop passed into my react component. Inline styling of React components I am pretty clear on, but I don't know how to correctly apply the inline style to change depending on a prop. I only want to assign the value of the prop `rightSideColor` in the inline styling of `right-toggle` if the prop `selected` is equal `true`.

```
export default function UiToggle(props) {
  const { leftLabel, rightLabel, selected, rightSideColor, leftSideColor } = props;

  return (
    <div className="lr-toggle-select" style={{ width: `${width}px` }} >
      <div className="lr-gray-background" />
      <div>
        {leftLabel}
      </div>
      <div className={'lr-toggle right-toggle' style={{ selected ? (backgroundColor: rightSideColor) : null }}>
        {rightLabel}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest placing all styling and also the conditional operator in a separate const.

```
export default function UiToggle(props) {

  const { leftLabel, rightLabel, selected, rightSideColor, leftSideColor } = props;

  const rightToggleStyle = {
     backgroundColor: selected ? rightSideColor : null
  };

  return (
    <div className="lr-toggle-select" style={{ width: `${width}px` }} >
      <div className="lr-gray-background" />
      <div>
        {leftLabel}
      </div>
      <div className="lr-toggle right-toggle" style={rightToggleStyle}>
        {rightLabel}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would try to do the same with the styling of the width. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed a typo - `{` before className

and you can return an empty object if *selected* is false else the expected value

Example:

```
export default function UiToggle(props) {
  const { leftLabel, rightLabel, selected, rightSideColor, leftSideColor } = props;

  return (
    <div className="lr-toggle-select" style={{ width: `${width}px` }} >
      <div className="lr-gray-background" />
      <div>
        {leftLabel}
      </div>
      <div className='lr-toggle right-toggle' style={ selected ? {backgroundColor: rightSideColor} : {} }}>
        {rightLabel}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally set the value of attributes like style, override them using rules of precedence, and determine whether to include them at all.

```
export default function UiToggle(props) {
  const { leftLabel, rightLabel, selected, rightSideColor, leftSideColor } = props;
  //specify style and id (and any other attributes) or don't.
  const attrs = selected ? { style: { backgroundColor: "rightSideColor" },id:"hi123" }:{}
  //Conditionally override the class names if we want:
  if (props.className) attrs.className = props.className

  return (
    <div className="lr-toggle-select" style={{ width: `${width}px` }} >
      <div className="lr-gray-background" />
      <div>
        {leftLabel}
      </div>

      {/*Use the spread operator to apply your attributes from attr*/}
      {/*Note that the 'id' set below can't be overridden by attrs whereas*/}
      {/*className will be. That's because precedence goes from right to left.*/}           
      {/*Rearrange them to get what you want.*/}
      {/*Funky comment format is to make valid JSX and also make SO formatter happy*/}          

      <div className='lr-toggle right-toggle' {...attrs} id="attrs_cant_override_this_because_its_on_the_right">
        {rightLabel}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   <div className='lr-toggle right-toggle' style={ selected ? {backgroundColor: rightSideColor} : '' }}>
    {rightLabel}
  </div>
```